# How to correctly pass authenticated user to queue Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send emails to new registered users.
Sending emails using a queue.
The job is added to the queue when the user is authenticated.

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

   public function login(Request $request)
    {

        $data = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:10', 'confirmed']
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($data, $request->input('remember'))) {

            $request->session()->regenerate();

            **SendEmail::dispatch(Auth::user());**

            return redirect()->route('web.category');
        }
        return to_route('login')->withErrors(['fail-login' => 'error']);
    }
```

**App\Jobs\SendEmail class:**

```
namespace App\Jobs;

 class SendEmail implements ShouldQueue
{

    public $user;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function handle(): void
    {
        **event(new Registered($this->user)); **
    }
```

As a result, emails are not sent because an unauthenticated user is passed to the Jobs/SendEmail class.

How did I check it?

The **handle** method of the SendEmail class dispatches the** Registered event** to the **SendEmailVerificationNotification listener**.

Next, the listener calls its own **handle method** in which it checks the user and if the check is passed, the letter is sent to the user.

And here are the test conditions `if ($event->user instanceof MustVerifyEmail && ! $event->user->hasVerifiedEmail())`.

The user does not pass this test.

What's my mistake?

Comment: You should dispatch the `SendEmail` job only if the user's email is verified. You would need to move the test conditions from the listener to the `LoginController`